# Upload Image Not accessible

Tags: images, windows

I'm getting a 500 error when trying to access the full version of any image. As soon as it's uploaded to the server, it becomes 'unavailable', and each file cannot be accessed/deleted/anything - like Wordpress is holding on to the file somehow. However, any thumbnails work fine.

We have tried:

- Changing permissions on the server
- Allowing media to be put into date and month folders, and to not be.
- Changing the folder that images get put into.

We're running a Windows 2008 install. Everything else seems to work but this. As I mentioned, the thumbnails are all fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an error log on your server?

Comment: Yes, nothing about the images at all. Only things in there are a couple of problems from code changes earlier today.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on your c:\Temp directory?  That is typically where PHP will send uploads initially and may be where it's getting caught up, rather than in the WordPress directories.

Comment: Yeah, tried that one, all is as expected.

Comment: Are you using IIS or Apache? Are permalinks enabled?

Comment: 1 : do you happen to use 1&1 host ? 2 : can we see your httaccess ??

Comment: Any solution to this?